# Looping in 2D-List JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the values for my function from the 2D List.

My 2D list value is defined as

```
List<List<String>> combined2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

After adding the values in to my List the structure is like below,

```
[[62744768, 62536400, 63689012, 63676486], [67888160, 67852422, 67299346, 68149470], [2017-09-06, 2017-09-05, 2017-09-17, 2017-09-15]]
```

I have a function with 3 parameters i.e,

```
FuncA(string param1,string param2,string param3)
{
//some operations
}
```

Now i want to pass the parameters of the FuncA by looping the 2D List Values.

**For Loop 1**

I have to get the 00,10,20 Index values from the List such as

> 62477,6780,2017-09-06

So that I will pass the parameters to my FuncA like

```
FuncA(62477,6780,2017-09-06)
```

**For Loop 2**

Like so for Loop 2 ,

```
FuncA(600,6785,2017-08-05)
```

**For Loop 3**

```
FuncA(12,646,2017-07-17)
```

**Up-to N loops...**

For a simple ArrayList I'm able to loop through like this

```
    for(String value:Singlearraylist) {
        FuncB(value);
    }
```

As I'm new to java I couldn't able to find the solution for my problem here.

Appreciate your response
JAY

Comment: To my mind, your data is misaligned, rather the laying it in columns, you should combine the parameters into a common object as rows

Comment: Provide your loop code so others can find where you're wrong

Comment: Can you at least try and post back ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer updated

Comment: You need to create object which can encapsulate `param1`, `param2` and `param3`, then you simply maintain a `List` of those objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] strings = new String[combined2d.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < combined2d.get(0).size(); i++){

   for (int j = 0; j < combined2d.size(); j++){
      strings[j] = combined2d.get(j).get(i);
   }

   FuncA(strings[0] strings[1], strings[2]);
}
```

I think this will work fine for you.

Comment: This way is wrong.As you are getting the 0,1, and 2 indexes.Which in turns obtain the 2D Index as 00,01,02. So you will get the values as {62744768,62536400,63689012} Which is not the actual case for me

Comment: @JayendranRosh check it now

Comment: Works perfectely

Answer (score 2):

If size of all the Lists are uneven, loop size should be minimum size of all given lists given in the 2-d list. Accordingly code can be written as forllows:

```java
List<List<String>> combined2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

int minTemp = Math.min(combined2d.get(0).size(),combined2d.get(1).size());
int min = Math.min(minTemp,combined2d.get(2).size());

for(int i=0; i<min ; i+= 10){
    FuncA(combined2d.get(0).get(i), combined2d.get(1).get(i), combined2d.get(2).get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @MadProgrammer suggested, create a class with data members `param1` `param2` `param3`with getters and setters and the list of this class's type, which you can use to iterate pass values to `FuncA(...,...,...)`

```
class Data{
    String param1, param2, param3;
    // constructors, getters and setters
}

List<Data> listData = new ArrayList<>();
for(Data temp : listData)FuncA(temp.getParam1(),temp.getParam2(),temp.getParam3());
```

And the way you create your list is the key here also as @MadProgrammer suggested in the comments. 
This way, your code is a lot easier to read and debug.